# how to setup my godaddy website to redirect to my ec2 java project

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to the AWS I created my java project.I want to open my website using my godaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open you AWS Account, Go to your EC2 Page

See at the botton in the description there is your Public IP is mentioned there.

Copy the Public IP Address.

Now Go to the Godaddy Account, in the main page click on DNS.
[image]

After opening the DNS configuration page.

Edit the **"A Type" and paste your Public IP address there**
[image]

### NOTE: its may take 15 minutes to 1 hour or more to take changes.